# WebGL: Set opacity when using texture2D()

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a simple WebGL scene created by Three.js for which I'm using a custom shader. The scene contains an image and I'd like to set the opacity of the image, but manipulating the `.a` attribute of `gl_FragColor` is not doing the trick.

Does anyone know how to set the opacity of an image in WebGL? I'd be grateful for any ideas others can offer on this question!

```html
<html>
<head>
  <style>
  html, body { width: 100%; height: 100%; background: #000; }
  body { margin: 0; overflow: hidden; }
  canvas { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/92/three.min.js'></script>
  <script src='https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/TrackballControls.js'></script>

  <script type='x-shader/x-vertex' id='vertex-shader'>
    uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;
    uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
    uniform vec3 cameraPosition;

    attribute vec2 uv;
    attribute vec3 position;

    varying vec2 vUv;

    void main() {
      vUv = uv;
      gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
    }
  </script>

  <script type='x-shader/x-fragment' id='fragment-shader'>
    precision highp float; // set float precision (optional)

    uniform sampler2D texture; // identify the texture as a uniform argument
    varying vec2 vUv; // identify the uv values as a varying attribute

    void main() {
      vec4 color = texture2D(texture, vUv);
      gl_FragColor = vec4(color[0], color[1], color[2], 0.0);
    }
  </script>

  <script>

  function getScene() {
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xffffff);
    return scene;
  }

  function getCamera() {
    var aspectRatio = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, aspectRatio, 0.1, 1000);
    camera.position.set(0, 1, 10);
    return camera;
  }

  function getRenderer() {
    // Create the canvas with a renderer
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
    // Add support for retina displays
    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    // Specify the size of the canvas
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    // Add the canvas to the DOM
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    return renderer;
  }

  function getControls(camera, renderer) {
    var controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
    controls.zoomSpeed = 0.4;
    controls.panSpeed = 0.4;
    return controls;
  }

  function loadImage() {

    var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();

    /*
    Now we need to push some vertices into that geometry to identify the coordinates the geometry should cover
    */

    // Identify the image size
    var imageSize = {width: 10, height: 7.5};

    // Identify the x, y, z coords where the image should be placed
    var coords = {x: -5, y: -3.75, z: 0};

    // Add one vertex for each corner of the image, using the
    // following order: lower left, lower right, upper right, upper left
    var vertices = new Float32Array([
      coords.x, coords.y, coords.z, // bottom left
      coords.x+imageSize.width, coords.y, coords.z, // bottom right
      coords.x+imageSize.width, coords.y+imageSize.height, coords.z, // upper right
      coords.x, coords.y+imageSize.height, coords.z, // upper left
    ])

    // set the uvs for this box; these identify the following corners:
    // lower-left, lower-right, upper-right, upper-left
    var uvs = new Float32Array([
      0.0, 0.0,
      1.0, 0.0,
      1.0, 1.0,
      0.0, 1.0,
    ])

    // indices = sequence of index positions in `vertices` to use as vertices
    // we make two triangles but only use 4 distinct vertices in the object
    // the second argument to THREE.BufferAttribute is the number of elements
    // in the first argument per vertex
    geometry.setIndex([0,1,2, 2,3,0])
    geometry.addAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute( vertices, 3 ));
    geometry.addAttribute('uv', new THREE.BufferAttribute( uvs, 2) )

    // Create a texture loader so we can load our image file
    var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

    // specify the url to the texture
    var url = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/duhaime/blog/tsne-webgl/assets/cat.jpg';

    // specify custom uniforms and attributes for shaders
    // Uniform types: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Uniforms-types
    var material = new THREE.RawShaderMaterial({
      uniforms: {
        texture: {
          type: 't',
          value: loader.load(url)
        },
        transparent: true,
      },
      vertexShader: document.getElementById('vertex-shader').textContent,
      fragmentShader: document.getElementById('fragment-shader').textContent
    });

    // Combine our image geometry and material into a mesh
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

    // Set the position of the image mesh in the x,y,z dimensions
    mesh.position.set(0,0,0)

    // Add the image to the scene
    scene.add(mesh);
  }

  /**
  * Render!
  **/

  function render() {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    controls.update();
  };

  var scene = getScene();
  var camera = getCamera();
  var renderer = getRenderer();
  var controls = getControls(camera, renderer);
  loadImage();

  render();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set

```
material.transparent = true;
```

Doing so will force normal alpha-blending to be set automatically by the renderer.

three.js r.95

Comment: Thanks @WestLangley. Now is there a way to set just the alpha degree of a textured point sprite (single vertex)? I plan to ask another question but thought you might be able to quickly verify if this is possible

Comment: Ah, it seems this is possible!